# Connecting to redis (from helm chart) inside Kubernetes cluster

Tags: redis, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've deployed a Kubernetes cluster via kubeadm on an Openstack cluster with 1 master and 1 node and allowed scheduling pods to both. The internal network is provided by Calico with default parameters. I install helm. I then used the redis helm chart to deploy redis, with the following config:

```
## Global Docker image registry
## Please, note that this will override the image registry for all the images, including dependencies, configured to use the global value
##
# global:
#   imageRegistry:

## Bitnami Redis image version
## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/redis/tags/
##
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: bitnami/redis
  ## Bitnami Redis image tag
  ## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis#supported-tags-and-respective-dockerfile-links
  ##
  tag: 5.0.3
  ## Specify a imagePullPolicy
  ## Defaults to 'Always' if image tag is 'latest', else set to 'IfNotPresent'
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#pre-pulling-images
  ##
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
  ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
  ##
  # pullSecrets:
  #   - myRegistrKeySecretName

## Cluster settings
cluster:
  enabled: true
  slaveCount: 1

networkPolicy:
  ## Specifies whether a NetworkPolicy should be created
  ##
  enabled: true

  ## The Policy model to apply. When set to false, only pods with the correct
  ## client label will have network access to the port Redis is listening
  ## on. When true, Redis will accept connections from any source
  ## (with the correct destination port).
  ##
  allowExternal: true

serviceAccount:
  ## Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  ##
  create: false
  ## The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  ## If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name:

rbac:
  ## Specifies whether RBAC resources should be created
  ##
  create: false

  role:
    ## Rules to create. It follows the role specification
    # rules:
    #  - apiGroups:
    #    - extensions
    #    resources:
    #      - podsecuritypolicies
    #    verbs:
    #      - use
    #    resourceNames:
    #      - gce.unprivileged
    rules: []

## Use password authentication
usePassword: false
## Redis password (both master and slave)
## Defaults to a random 10-character alphanumeric string if not set and usePassword is true
## ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis#setting-the-server-password-on-first-run
##
password:
## Use existing secret (ignores previous password)
# existingSecret:

## Mount secrets as files instead of environment variables
usePasswordFile: false

## Persist data to a persistent volume
persistence:
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  existingClaim: redis-store-pvc

##
## Redis Master parameters
##
master:
  ## Redis port
  port: 6379
  ## Redis command arguments
  ##
  ## Can be used to specify command line arguments, for example:
  ##
  command:
  - "/run.sh"
  ## Redis additional command line flags
  ##
  ## Can be used to specify command line flags, for example:
  ##
  ## extraFlags:
  ##  - "--maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl"
  ##  - "--repl-backlog-size 1024mb"
  extraFlags: []
  ## Comma-separated list of Redis commands to disable
  ##
  ## Can be used to disable Redis commands for security reasons.
  ## Commands will be completely disabled by renaming each to an empty string.
  ## ref: https://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands
  ##
  disableCommands:
#  - FLUSHDB
#  - FLUSHALL

  ## Redis Master additional pod labels and annotations
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/
  podLabels: {}
  podAnnotations: {}

  ## Redis Master resource requests and limits
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  # resources:
  #   requests:
  #     memory: 256Mi
  #     cpu: 100m
  ## Use an alternate scheduler, e.g. "stork".
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
  ##
  # schedulerName:

  ## Configure extra options for Redis Master liveness and readiness probes
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes)
  ##
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 5
    timeoutSeconds: 5
    successThreshold: 1
    failureThreshold: 5
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 5
    timeoutSeconds: 1
    successThreshold: 1
    failureThreshold: 5

  ## Redis Master Node selectors and tolerations for pod assignment
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#taints-and-tolerations-beta-feature
  ##
  # nodeSelector: {"beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64"}
  # tolerations: []
  ## Redis Master pod/node affinity/anti-affinity
  ##
  affinity: {}

  ## Redis Master Service properties
  service:
    ##  Redis Master Service type
    type: ClusterIP
    port: 6379

    ## Specify the nodePort value for the LoadBalancer and NodePort service types.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport
    ##
    # nodePort:

    ## Provide any additional annotations which may be required. This can be used to
    ## set the LoadBalancer service type to internal only.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer
    ##
    annotations: {}
    loadBalancerIP:

  ## Redis Master Pod Security Context
  securityContext:
    enabled: true
    fsGroup: 1001
    runAsUser: 1001

  ## Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
  ##
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    ## The path the volume will be mounted at, useful when using different
    ## Redis images.
    path: /redis-store
    ## The subdirectory of the volume to mount to, useful in dev environments
    ## and one PV for multiple services.
    subPath: /data
    ## redis data Persistent Volume Storage Class
    ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
    ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
    ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
    ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
    ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
    ##
    # storageClass: "-"
    storageClass: local-storage
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    size: 90Gi

  ## Update strategy, can be set to RollingUpdate or onDelete by default.
  ## https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#updating-statefulsets
  statefulset:
    updateStrategy: RollingUpdate
    ## Partition update strategy
    ## https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#partitions
    # rollingUpdatePartition:

  ## Redis Master pod priorityClassName
  # priorityClassName: {}


##
## Redis Slave properties
## Note: service.type is a mandatory parameter
## The rest of the parameters are either optional or, if undefined, will inherit those declared in Redis Master
##
slave:
  ## Slave Service properties
  service:
    ## Redis Slave Service type
    type: ClusterIP
    ## Specify the nodePort value for the LoadBalancer and NodePort service types.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport
    ##
    # nodePort:

    ## Provide any additional annotations which may be required. This can be used to
    ## set the LoadBalancer service type to internal only.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer
    ##
    annotations: {}
    loadBalancerIP:

  ## Redis port
  # port: 6379
  ## Redis extra flags
  # extraFlags: []
  ## List of Redis commands to disable
  # disableCommands: []

  ## Redis Slave pod/node affinity/anti-affinity
  ##
  affinity: {}

  ## Configure extra options for Redis Slave liveness and readiness probes
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes)
  ##
  # livenessProbe:
  #   enabled: true
  #   initialDelaySeconds: 30
  #   periodSeconds: 10
  #   timeoutSeconds: 5
  #   successThreshold: 1
  #   failureThreshold: 5
  # readinessProbe:
  #   enabled: true
  #   initialDelaySeconds: 5
  #   periodSeconds: 10
  #   timeoutSeconds: 10
  #   successThreshold: 1
  #   failureThreshold: 5

  ## Redis slave Resource
  # resources:
  #   requests:
  #     memory: 256Mi
  #     cpu: 100m

  ## Redis slave selectors and tolerations for pod assignment
  # nodeSelector: {"beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64"}
  # tolerations: []

  ## Use an alternate scheduler, e.g. "stork".
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
  ##
  # schedulerName:

  ## Redis slave pod Annotation and Labels
  # podLabels: {}
  # podAnnotations: {}

  ## Redis slave pod Security Context
  # securityContext:
  #   enabled: true
  #   fsGroup: 1001
  #   runAsUser: 1001

  ## Redis slave pod priorityClassName
  # priorityClassName: {}

## Prometheus Exporter / Metrics
##
metrics:
  enabled: false

  image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: oliver006/redis_exporter
    tag: v0.25.0
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ## Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
    ## Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
    ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
    ##
    # pullSecrets:
    #   - myRegistrKeySecretName

  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    ## Use serviceLoadBalancerIP to request a specific static IP,
    ## otherwise leave blank
    # loadBalancerIP:
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      prometheus.io/port: "9121"

  ## Metrics exporter resource requests and limits
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  ##
  # resources: {}

  ## Extra arguments for Metrics exporter, for example:
  ## extraArgs:
  ##   check-keys: myKey,myOtherKey
  # extraArgs: {}

  ## Metrics exporter labels and tolerations for pod assignment
  # nodeSelector: {"beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64"}
  # tolerations: []

  ## Metrics exporter pod Annotation and Labels
  # podAnnotations: {}
  # podLabels: {}

  # Enable this if you're using https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: false
    ## Specify a namespace if needed
    # namespace: monitoring
    # fallback to the prometheus default unless specified
    # interval: 10s
    ## Defaults to what's used if you follow CoreOS [Prometheus Install Instructions](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#tldr)
    ## [Prometheus Selector Label](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#prometheus-operator-1)
    ## [Kube Prometheus Selector Label](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#exporters)
    selector:
      prometheus: kube-prometheus

  ## Metrics exporter pod priorityClassName
  # priorityClassName: {}

##
## Init containers parameters:
## volumePermissions: Change the owner of the persist volume mountpoint to RunAsUser:fsGroup
##
volumePermissions:
  image:
    registry: docker.io
    repository: bitnami/minideb
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

## Redis config file
## ref: https://redis.io/topics/config
##
configmap: |-
  # maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
```

So far so good, the pods deploy successfully. I can see the network policy being created:

```
[root@tracker redis]# kubectl describe  networkpolicy redis 
Name:         redis
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2019-01-26 10:09:23 +0000 UTC
Labels:       app=redis
              chart=redis-5.3.0
              heritage=Tiller
              release=redis
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     app=redis,release=redis
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: 6379/TCP
    From: <any> (traffic not restricted by source)
  Allowing egress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for egress connectivity)
  Policy Types: Ingress
```

I now launched a pod with the redis client to test connecting to the redis server and the client is not able to establish a connection with redis-master. I checked that the name properly resolves to the service IP. I tried accessing the service by IP, and the pod that runs the redis-master directly by ip, and none of these work.

I can log directly onto the pod that runs redis-master and create a client session there. I can actually port forward from outside the kubernetes cluster using

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/redis-master 6379:6379 &
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
```

and this does work. I installed netstat on the redis-master pod and it looks like the service is bound on 0.0.0.0 so should be accepting outside connections:

```
Every 2.0s: netstat -at                                                                                      

    redis-master-0: Sat Jan 26 11:24:13 2019

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I guess it's something about the internal cluster networking that's tripping this up but I don't know how to debug it further. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by switching over to the weave network provider. It is still unclear why calico was not working.